# Bash script printing

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
list=$(find $1 -not -empty -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -rn | uniq -d | xargs -I{} -n1 find -type f -size {}c -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate)
echo $list
```

It finds files with the same content and sorts them. If I run this in terminal just like that it prints nicely, but when I run this in script

```
printf "%s\n"
```

it doesn't work and it looks ugly, how can I fix that? I'm new to this bash scripting, it's probably super easy.

Comment: What do you mean by "ugly"? Try `echo "$list"` (echo with quotes).

Comment: Wow it worked, like I said, super easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: Unless you are doing something else with `list`, there is no reason to capture the output of the pipeline just to use it with `echo`. Just use `find ... | sort ...| ...`